# Animated overlays for Android

Tags: android, overlay, android-mapview, itemizedoverlay

I need to develop animation on map View overlay.
One animation take place when user tap on current location (my current location is my own png) - my overlay should bounce. Second animation take place when overlays appear on map - it should fall from top.

I was googling and explore SO for some answers - lack of information. Is anybody has experience or know how to handle this -  please help me.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

I can only refer to this libary I used myself:
[GoogleMapsOverlay](http://code.google.com/p/mapview-overlay-manager/)

it has many build in features, like an OverlayGestureListener You can use to determine when a user taps once or twice on an item (like your position). Second helpful thing for you might be the lazyload-manager. For the animations I would suggest a state-drawable for the bouncing.